# Where does Internet Explorer store saved passwords?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, passwords, password-protection

Where does Internet Explorer store saved passwords?

And since this is a programming site, I'm not literally asking for the location where IE stores passwords, **but which API IE uses to save passwords**.

At first I assumed that Microsoft was using the standard api:

- [`CredRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374804(VS.85).aspx)
- [`CredWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375187(VS.85).aspx)

which is used to save domain *and* generic program/web-site credentials.

`CredRead`/`CredWrite` then turn around around and use:

- [`CryptProtectData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261(VS.85).aspx)
- [`CryptUnprotectData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380882(v=VS.85).aspx)

to encrypt data with the current user's account. `CredRead`/`CredWrite` then store the data in some magical location, contents of which you can see from the Control Panel:

[image]

But I don't see IE passwords in there. So IE doesn't store passwords using `CredRead`/`CredWrite`.

What API does IE use to store passwords, and if it uses `CryptProtectData`, where does it then store the protected data?

---

**Edit:** The reason I ask needs no explanation (since it's pretty obvious), but it's because I might want to use the same mechanism.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer. IE stores passwords in two different locations based on the password type:

- **Http-Auth:** `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Credentials`, in encrypted files
- **Form-based:** `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet  Explorer\IntelliForms\Storage2`, encrypted with the url

From a [very good page on NirSoft.com](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_password.html):

> Starting from version 7.0 of Internet
>   Explorer, Microsoft completely changed
>   the way that passwords are saved. In
>   previous versions (4.0 - 6.0), all
>   passwords were saved in a special
>   location in the Registry known as the
>   "Protected Storage".  In version 7.0
>   of Internet Explorer, passwords are
>   saved in different locations,
>   depending on the type of password.
>   Each type of passwords has some
>   limitations in password recovery:
>
> - **AutoComplete Passwords:** These
>     passwords are saved in the following
>     location in the Registry:
>     `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>     Explorer\IntelliForms\Storage2`  The
>     passwords are encrypted with the URL
>     of the Web sites that asked for the
>     passwords, and thus they can only be
>     recovered if the URLs are stored in
>     the history file. If you clear the
>     history file, IE PassView won't be
>     able to recover the passwords until
>     you visit again the Web sites that
>     asked for the passwords.
>     Alternatively, you can add a list of
>     URLs of Web sites that requires user
>     name/password into the Web sites file
>     (see below).
> - **HTTP Authentication
>     Passwords:** These passwords are stored
>     in the Credentials file under
>     `Documents and Settings\Application
>     Data\Microsoft\Credentials`, together
>     with login passwords of LAN computers
>     and other passwords.  Due to security
>     limitations, IE PassView can recover
>     these passwords only if you have
>     administrator rights.

In my particular case it answers the question of where; and I decided that I don't want to duplicate that. I'll continue to use `CredRead`/`CredWrite`, where the user can manage their passwords from within an established UI system in Windows.

Comment: Can you retrieve them if they are on an old hard drive sitting on the shelf?  Not you as in YOU but you in the general sense. :)

Comment: @dlackey Conceptually it is possible, as long as you know your old Windows password.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** in the Vault. Since Windows 7, a Vault was created for storing any sensitive data among it the credentials of Internet Explorer.
The Vault is in fact a LocalSystem service - vaultsvc.dll.

**Long answer:**
Internet Explorer allows two methods of credentials storage: web sites credentials (for example: your Facebook user and password) and autocomplete data. Since version 10, instead of using the Registry a new term was introduced: Windows Vault. Windows Vault is the default storage vault for the credential manager information.

You need to check which OS is running. If its Windows 8 or greater, you call **VaultGetItemW8**. If its isn't, you call **VaultGetItemW7**.

To use the "Vault", you load a DLL named "vaultcli.dll" and access its functions as needed.

A typical C++ code will be:

```
hVaultLib = LoadLibrary(L"vaultcli.dll");

if (hVaultLib != NULL) 
{
    pVaultEnumerateItems = (VaultEnumerateItems)GetProcAddress(hVaultLib, "VaultEnumerateItems");
    pVaultEnumerateVaults = (VaultEnumerateVaults)GetProcAddress(hVaultLib, "VaultEnumerateVaults");
    pVaultFree = (VaultFree)GetProcAddress(hVaultLib, "VaultFree");
    pVaultGetItemW7 = (VaultGetItemW7)GetProcAddress(hVaultLib, "VaultGetItem");
    pVaultGetItemW8 = (VaultGetItemW8)GetProcAddress(hVaultLib, "VaultGetItem");
    pVaultOpenVault = (VaultOpenVault)GetProcAddress(hVaultLib, "VaultOpenVault");
    pVaultCloseVault = (VaultCloseVault)GetProcAddress(hVaultLib, "VaultCloseVault");

    bStatus = (pVaultEnumerateVaults != NULL)
        && (pVaultFree != NULL)
        && (pVaultGetItemW7 != NULL)
        && (pVaultGetItemW8 != NULL)
        && (pVaultOpenVault != NULL)
        && (pVaultCloseVault != NULL)
        && (pVaultEnumerateItems != NULL);
}
```

Then you enumerate all stored credentials by calling

```
VaultEnumerateVaults
```

Then you go over the results.

Answer (score 0):

No guarantee, but I suspect IE uses the older [Protected Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432403%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.

Comment: You're partially right. Internet Explorer 4-6 uses the Protected Storage API. IE 7-8 store passwords in the registry, and a file, depending on the password type.

Comment: PSAPI was deprecated a long time ago.  IE6 used it last.